# How do I aggregate transaction data for reporting? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, reporting, data-warehouse, aggregation, business-intelligence

I have some data that looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
| id | timestamp | amount | product | method |
+----+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
|  1 | 6/5/2018  |      4 | apple   | cash   |
|  2 | 6/5/2018  |      7 | apple   | cash   |
|  3 | 6/6/2018  |      3 | orange  | card   |
|  4 | 6/6/2018  |      9 | orange  | cash   |
|  5 | 6/7/2018  |      4 | orange  | card   |
|  6 | 6/7/2018  |      8 | apple   | card   |
+----+-----------+--------+---------+--------+
```

There are hundreds of thousands of transactions per day.

I want to generate charts off of this data which can be either at the daily, weekly, monthly or multi-month level. I was thinking I should write some c# code to loop through each day, product, method combination and then run a query to get the totals and produce data like this:

```
+------+-------+-----+------------+-----------+-------+
| year | month | day | dimProduct | dimMethod | total |
+------+-------+-----+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2018 |     6 |   5 | apple      | cash      |    11 |
| 2018 |     6 |   5 | apple      | card      |     0 |
| 2018 |     6 |   6 | apple      | cash      |     0 |
| 2018 |     6 |   6 | apple      | card      |     0 |
| 2018 |     6 |   7 | apple      | cash      |     0 |
| 2018 |     6 |   7 | apple      | card      |     8 |
| 2018 |     6 |   5 | orange     | cash      |     0 |
| 2018 |     6 |   5 | orange     | card      |     0 |
| 2018 |     6 |   6 | orange     | cash      |     9 |
| 2018 |     6 |   6 | orange     | card      |     3 |
| 2018 |     6 |   7 | orange     | cash      |     0 |
| 2018 |     6 |   7 | orange     | card      |     4 |
+------+-------+-----+------------+-----------+-------+
```

But then I thought... there has to be a better way than writing code which runs millions of queries and takes days to run and then is difficult to update as new data comes in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just index and maybe partition your table, then report off it as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to generate data which is not present as well, you would need to include your database engine, because the answer will be vendor specific.

---

For the data you already have you need to extract date parts from your date column, group them and include `sum(amount)` as total:

```
select
  year(timestamp) as year,
  month(timestamp) as month,
  day(timestamp) as day,
  product as "dimProduct",
  method as "dimMethod",
  sum(amount) as total
from yourtable
group by year(timestamp), month(timestamp), day(timestamp), product, method
```

Comment: Did you try the query? From what I understand you want to show up records everyday from min date to max date for each product and method even if they aren't in source table (data) to have amount 0. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could add DimDate instead of breaking down the date elements. Than create Fact tables with aggregated data.